# How do run a query multiple times with a different variable, and union the answers?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to run a query for all the days between 11/02/2019 - 12/02/2019

```
SELECT sum(traffic_cost)
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT ON (table_a.keyword) traffic_cost
       FROM table_a
       WHERE timestamp <= '2019-12-02'
       ORDER BY keyword, timestamp DESC
     ) table_a
```

The output should look like this:

```
date       sum
2019-12-02 500
2019-12-01 600
2019-11-30 700
...
```

EDIT: This is different than an normal GROUP BY. `table_a` has multiple rows with the same keyword and different dates. So in the first query, I am saying "Give me the latest date no later that 2019-12-02", but then I want to run it again saying "Give me the latest date no later than 2019-12-01" and so on...

In sudo code, it would look like:

`For each date in [2019-12-02 ..... 2019-10-01]: run the query above using that date, save the output as a row`

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for a simple `SUM … GROUP BY timestamp`?

Comment: Yes. I want to set the maximum allowed date each time, and decrease it

Comment: So essentially you want an running `SUM` without grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query returns just one row and one column, just make it a subquery to a query  which returns each date, and make your hard coded date a reference to the date from that outer query.

```
select date, 
    (SELECT sum(traffic_cost) FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT ON (table_a.keyword) traffic_cost
       FROM table_a
       WHERE timestamp <= date
       ORDER BY keyword, timestamp DESC) table_a
    ) as sum  
from generate_series('2019-10-01','2019-12-02',interval '1 day') f(date);
```